# How to verify the Azure DevOps Private URL is working?

Tags: security, azure-devops, privacy

I have configured the Private URL for my organization under Organizational setting. Kinldy let me know how to verify the Privacy on accessing the URL.

On accessing the URL Will we (people who are in the AD) get any pop-up ? (or) how to check security of the site .

Thanks,
Santhosh Kannna

Comment: Even on turning of the toggle button and entering a new URL and on accessing it we are getting 401 error .

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to define a custom URL for the Azure DevOps organization. As of this time, however, this feature is not supported.

The "Privacy URL" you have set is the **privacy policy URL**, which is used to describe your policies and procedures, use and disclosure of visitors information, and so on. It is generally used in public projects.

If you want to work under your custom url, you might consider [Azure DevOps Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/what-is-azure-devops?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fserver%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fserver%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops-2020#choose-azure-devops-server) instead of Azure DevOps Service.